# Checking null objects in JsonPath

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

I'm trying to validate some JsonPath objects for Gatling simulations and it's working fine for non-null objects but it's failing for "null" objects.

Actually the String "null" and object null comparision get failed, how can I handle this situation ?

We are checking error as below,

```
.check(jsonPath("$.userId").ofType[String].is("null"))
```

OR

```
.check(jsonPath("$.userId").ofType[Any].is(null))
```

But, get error as

```
failed: jsonPath($.userId).find.is(null), but actually found null
```

any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better answer than my first one would be:

```
jsonPath("$.userId").ofType[Option[String]].not(None)
```

After all, this is Scala; we don't take kindly to `null` around here.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because Gatling lacks a `JsonFilter` for `Option`. Not hard to write, though:

```
implicit def optionJsonFilter[T : JsonFilter] : JsonFilter[Option[T]] = {
  new JsonFilter[Option[T]] {
    def filter = {
      case null  => None
      case other => {
        val subfilter : JsonFilter[T] = implicitly
        Some(subfilter.filter(other))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(If it's the future and Gatling has fixed this, please do edit this.)

Comment: Thanks @Luke, please prapose a PR for Gatling https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2997#issuecomment-307425988

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your efforts _/\_

Answer (score 3):

You can use the original Gatlin DSL API for `null` checking:

```
check(jsonPath("$.userId").notNull)
```

For more details see [Validating](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#validating)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Gatling check system isn't set up to handle `null` very well; it's assumed that everything uses `Option`, but that's not how its JSON handling works.

You can use the more general `validate()` method to fix this, though. First define a simple validator:

```
def notNull[T] = new Validator[T] {
  val name = "notNull"
  def apply(actual : Option[T]) : Validation[Option[T]] = {
    actual match {
      case Some(null) => Failure("but it's so null you guys")
      case _          => Success(actual)
    }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.userId")).validate(notNull[String])
```